# Zero count on product collection after adding a price attribute

Tags: price, product-collection

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
```

If I `echo count($collection);` I get the expected response. However, if prior to that

```
$collection->addFinalPrice();
```

I get a zero size on the collection count. What is causing this?

Comment: please try this $collection->count();

Comment: Either way (`echo count($collection);` or `echo $collection->count();`) it returns zero (0).

Comment: please reindex the system

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze your SQL query before and after

```
$collection->addFinalPrice();
```

by using this line

```
<?php echo (string)$collection->getSelect(); ?>
```

Comment: Before: `SELECT 'e'.* FROM 'catalog_product_entity' AS 'e'` and after: `SELECT 'e'.*, 'price_index'.'price', 'price_index'.'tax_class_id', 'price_index'.'final_price', IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS 'minimal_price', 'price_index'.'min_price', 'price_index'.'max_price', 'price_index'.'tier_price' FROM 'catalog_product_entity' AS 'e' INNER JOIN 'catalog_product_index_price' AS 'price_index' ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '0' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0`

Comment: Your query is correct, try to run it using MySQL client (HeidiSQL for example) to see the result [https://www.evernote.com/shard/s411/sh/f9b878d2-edd8-4614-b3d4-4e33e20f15d0/efd8f6988365d439e5a2e929287de49e](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s411/sh/f9b878d2-edd8-4614-b3d4-4e33e20f15d0/efd8f6988365d439e5a2e929287de49e)

Answer (score 0):

Try reindexing your shop (catalog_product_price).

I have experienced a similar problem when I created a new website in Magento and attached products to it.
Because the indexer did not run, the prices were unknown in the database as well. And if they are unknown, your product will not be picked up in the productCollection and will be empty.